# Error react-native run-windows " Unable to get property 'Direction' of undefined or null reference"

Tags: javascript, react-native, node-modules, react-native-windows, react-native-gesture-handler

I get an error when I want to run the react-native run-windows app ...
When the app opens, an error appears,

```
Unable to get the 'Direction' property of undefined or null reference
```

The error appears after I installed react-native-gesture-handler ...

Can anyone provide a solution to solve this problem?

thank you

Comment: Can you share the code that causes this error?

Comment: you have to follow a few steps as per the installation guide of `react-native-gesture-handler` like running command `react-native link` and other steps. just giving a random uggestion as you have not provided detailed query.

Comment: Ah can be resolved, I reinstalled the react-native-gesture-handler with a version a little longer than now.